# Rails app crashed with #<ArgumentError: uncaught throw {:__recursive_key__=>true, 20687660=>true}>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

We are running a rails app with quite alot of requests ( 400 requests per minute ) with 3 webnodes running nginx and passenger.

However the past days we have experienced several crashes with a 500 error. Theres nothing to be found in the nginx error log. The rails log gives a rather non-describing errormessage, which i hope some of you guys can help me to track down:

```
ArgumentError: uncaught throw {:__recursive_key__=>true, 20687660=>true}
```

Stack trace:

```
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:57:in `block in nary'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:57:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:57:in `nary'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `block in visit_Array'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `visit_Array'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:146:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectCore'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `block in visit_Array'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:169:in `visit_Array'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:153:in `visit_Arel_Nodes_SelectStatement'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:29:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/depth_first.rb:12:in `visit'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/visitors/visitor.rb:9:in `accept'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/arel-6.0.3/lib/arel/nodes/node.rb:56:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:210:in `grep'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:210:in `perform_calculation'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:127:in `calculate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:42:in `count'
/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/models/webshop.rb:135:in `show_custom_pickup_identifier?'
/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/controllers/standard/shopify_controller.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in shop_shipping'
/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/controllers/standard/shopify_controller.rb:173:in `each'
/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/controllers/standard/shopify_controller.rb:173:in `block in shop_shipping'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/controllers/standard/shopify_controller.rb:157:in `shop_shipping'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.2.4/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:97:in `process_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:160:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:113:in `main_loop'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:416:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:113:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
```

It seems to happen all different places in the app, except when theres no need for database queries. Our db however seems healthy and has alot of capacity in terms of connections, memory and cpu.

Hope somebody can give me a clue on how to resolve this.

Thanks :-)

Comment: what's in `/var/www/app/releases/20160607074820/app/models/webshop.rb:135:in `show_custom_pickup_identifier?'` ? (or are you saying that this is not always what throws the exception?)

Comment: Are you using `pp` in your code (pretty print)? If so, can you try to comment it out? I found the only references of `__recursive_key__` in the ruby `pp` classes (and also in `puma`).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions :-)

The exception does throw periodically - but it seems to be on database calls only ( - in show_custom_pickup_identifier? it only makes a simple AR query ). So i tracked it down - and we think we found the problem in AWS RDS IOPS limitation. After applying more storage ( hence more IOPS ) it seems to have gone away - today at least :-) It would be nice if amazon had a clear indicator that we were out of IOPS (!!)..

So for now we will cross our fingers that this will permanently resolve the issue :-)

Comment: I am facing the same issues, does apply more storage works for you?

Answer (score -1):

This happens when a method goes in a redirect loop. This starts eating your IOPS.

You would get a Stack level too deep error.